# Getting "Gradle sync failed: connection reset" in Android Studio

Tags: java, windows, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

While creating a simple project in Android Studio, I am getting this error.

The log file for your reference:

```
2018-08-13 10:56:47,583 [e-1024-b02]   INFO - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Started sync with Gradle for project 'My Application'. 
2018-08-13 10:56:47,591 [e-1024-b02]   INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Consuming IndexingSuspender activation event: SYNC_STARTED 
2018-08-13 10:56:47,591 [e-1024-b02]   INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Starting batch update for project: Project 'C:\Users\surya.s02\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication' My Application 
2018-08-13 10:56:47,624 [thread 380]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/jre 
2018-08-13 10:56:47,631 [thread 380]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/jre 
2018-08-13 10:56:47,998 [thread 380]   INFO - xecution.GradleExecutionHelper - Passing command-line args to Gradle Tooling API: -Didea.version=3.1 -Djava.awt.headless=true -Pandroid.injected.build.model.only=true -Pandroid.injected.build.model.only.advanced=true -Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true -Pandroid.injected.build.model.only.versioned=3 -Pandroid.injected.studio.version=3.1.3.0 -Pandroid.builder.sdkDownload=false --init-script C:\Users\surya.s02\AppData\Local\Temp\ijinit.gradle 
2018-08-13 10:58:35,124 [thread 380]   INFO - .project.GradleProjectResolver - Gradle project resolve error 
org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:51)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'MyApplication'.
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultExceptionAnalyser.transform(DefaultExceptionAnalyser.java:74)
    at org.gradle.initialization.MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.transform(MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.java:47)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:45)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'MyApplication'.
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:94)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.doConfigure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:66)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$100(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:34)


Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultConfiguration.java:918)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$1600(DefaultConfiguration.java:116)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:892)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:404)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration_Decorated.getFiles(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.iterator(AbstractFileCollection.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.DefaultClassPath.<init>(DefaultClassPath.java:48)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultScriptClassPathResolver.resolveClassPath(DefaultScriptClassPathResolver.java:39)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.doConfigure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:64)
    ... 81 more
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:1.2.0.
Required by:
    project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.3
    project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.3 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.1.3
    project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.3 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:26.1.3
    project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.3 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:3.1.3
    project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.3 > com.android.databinding:compilerCommon:3.1.3
    project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.3 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.1.3 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:26.1.3
    project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.3 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.1.3 > com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:26.1.3
    project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.3 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.1.3 > com.android.tools:sdklib:26.1.3 > com.android.tools:repository:26.1.3
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.resolveModule(RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.java:103)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.resolve(RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.ComponentResolversChain$ComponentMetaDataResolverChain.resolve(ComponentResolversChain.java:93)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.clientmodule.ClientModuleResolver.resolve(ClientModuleResolver.java:48)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.ComponentState.resolve(ComponentState.java:157)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.ComponentState.getMetaData(ComponentState.java:168)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.EdgeState.calculateTargetConfigurations(EdgeState.java:134)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.EdgeState.attachToTargetConfigurations(EdgeState.java:105)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.DependencyGraphBuilder.attachToTargetRevisionsSerially(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:239)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator.withContentIfPresent(BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator.java:229)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.copyToCache(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:199)
    ... 148 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:394)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.upgrade(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.upgrade(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:369)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:415)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performHttpRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:148)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performHttpRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:126)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.executeGetOrHead(HttpClientHelper.java:103)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:94)
    ... 163 more
2018-08-13 10:58:35,148 [thread 380]   WARN - nal.AbstractExternalSystemTask - Connection reset 
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: Connection reset
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.ProjectImportErrorHandler.getUserFriendlyError(ProjectImportErrorHandler.java:72)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.getUserFriendlyError(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:436)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.getUserFriendlyError(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:158)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:943)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:923)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:210)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:140)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:165)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:315)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:394)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.upgrade(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.upgrade(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:369)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:415)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performHttpRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:148)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performHttpRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:126)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.executeGetOrHead(HttpClientHelper.java:103)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:94)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRawGet(HttpClientHelper.java:80)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performGet(HttpClientHelper.java:84)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpResourceAccessor.openResource(HttpResourceAccessor.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpResourceAccessor.openResource(HttpResourceAccessor.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultExternalResourceConnector.openResource(DefaultExternalResourceConnector.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.ProgressLoggingExternalResourceAccessor.openResource(ProgressLoggingExternalResourceAccessor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.AccessorBackedExternalResource.withContentIfPresent(AccessorBackedExternalResource.java:130)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator$11.call(BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator.java:237)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator$11.call(BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator.java:229)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:82)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)

2018-08-13 10:58:35,174 [thread 380]   WARN - ect.sync.idea.ProjectSetUpTask - Connection reset 
2018-08-13 10:58:35,175 [thread 380]   INFO - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Gradle sync failed: Connection reset

Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (1m 47s 591ms) 
2018-08-13 10:58:35,233 [e-1024-b02]   INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Consuming IndexingSuspender deactivation event: SYNC_FINISHED 
2018-08-13 10:58:35,233 [e-1024-b02]   INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Finishing batch update for project: Project 'C:\Users\surya.s02\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication' My Application 
2018-08-13 10:58:35,435 [thread 379]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Clearing symbols finished in 0 s. 
2018-08-13 10:58:35,436 [thread 379]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols in FAST mode, 0 source files from total 0 project files 
2018-08-13 10:58:35,446 [thread 379]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loading Module Maps finished in 0 s. 
2018-08-13 10:58:35,450 [thread 379]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving Module Maps finished in 0 s. 
2018-08-13 10:58:35,451 [thread 379]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving Module Maps finished in 0 s. 
2018-08-13 10:58:35,451 [thread 379]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loaded 0 tables for 0 files (0 project files) 
2018-08-13 10:58:35,463 [thread 379]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols for 0 source files 
2018-08-13 10:58:35,497 [thread 379]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols for 0 unused headers 
2018-08-13 10:58:35,497 [thread 379]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols finished in 0 s. 
2018-08-13 10:58:35,498 [thread 379]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving modified symbols for 0 files (0 tables of total 0) 
2018-08-13 10:58:35,498 [thread 379]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving symbols finished in 0 s. 
2018-08-13 11:04:22,331 [e-1024-b02]   INFO - ide.actions.ShowFilePathAction - 
Exit code 1
```

Answer (score 6):

Just  go to the .gradle folder in your Users/{username}/.gradle. Open gradle properties if there are proxy settings, comment them out and save it.(This problem might occur because Android studio does not automatically clear proxy cache settings). And Sync your project

Answer (score 1):

For Android studio 3.0.0

required Gradle version: 4.1

File > Project Structure > Project

required Build Tools 26.0.2

Answer (score 0):

Add google repository to your gradle file:

```
repositories {
    maven()
    //other repositories...
    google()
}
```

Try to download from SDK manager: SDK Manager Android Studio

Check your gradle and plugin version:
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html#updating-gradle

Answer (score 0):

go to `gradle.properties` and delete all `proxy` you added before .
and save it and back to Android Studio and Sync it again .